# Sanity check on AWS Big Data Architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, architecture, amazon-athena

We're currently looking to move our AWS architecture over to something that supports large amounts of data and can scale as we gain more customers. When this project started we stuck with what we knew, a Ruby app on an EC2 making RESTful API calls, storing the results in S3, and also storing everything in an RDS. We have a SPA front end written in VueJS to support the stored data.

As our client list has grown, the outbound API calls and subsequence data we are storing is also growing. I'm currently tasked with looking for a better solution and I wanted to get a sense of feedback on what I was thinking so far. Currently we have around 5 millions rows of relational data which will only increase as our client list does. I could see in a year or two we would be in the low billions or rows.

The Ruby app does a great job of handling queuing the outbound API calls, retries, and everything else in-between. For this reason we thought about keeping the app and rather than inserting directly into the RDS, it would simply dump the results into S3 as a CSV.

A trigger in S3 could now convert the raw CSV data into parquet format using a Lambda function (I was looking at something like PyArrow). From here we could move over from the traditional RDS to something like Athena which supports parquet and would allow us to reuse most of our existing SQL queries.

To further optimize the performance for the user we thought about caching commonly used queries in a Dynamo table. Because the data is based on the scheduled external API calls, we could control when to bust the cache of the queries.

Big Data backends aren't really my thing, so any feedback is greatly appreciated. I know I have a lot more research to do into parquet as it's new to me. Eventually we'd like to do some ML on this data, so I believe parquet will also support thanks.

Comment: Big data is billions of rows, not millions (and really, given today's architectures, 100s of billions of rows or more). Your problem is a simple optimization issue, and you need to spend time identifying where the bottlenecks are in your current architecture. If something isn't CPU-bound or IO-bound, it's not a bottleneck. Personally, I'm betting on your Ruby app.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback. The ruby isn't the bottle neck. The api calls it makes and then stores in the RDS works perfectly fine. But even with a few million rows for a few customers with all the indexes possible, our queries are starting to slow. Within a few years I could easily see us in the lower end of billions of rows.

Comment: Also, our current implementation doesn't seem to allow us to perform ML on the data easily, where converting everything to parquet seems to check that box for a future need.

Comment: :shrug: have fun

Comment: SparkSQL should be able to query RDS and do MlLib pipelines just fine. It might only be slightly slower than S3 Parquet (or ORC) reads